# How to include external javascript functions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to refer a external javascript file by calling a function in that file as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="external.js">
display('hell0');
</script>
```

But this code is not working. If i refer the file in separdate script tag it works fine.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">  
    display('hell0');
    </script>
```

Why the first case is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `src` attribute to specify an external javascript file to be included you cannot have contents to this `script` tag. The second case is the correct way.

Quote from the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1):

> The script may be defined within the
>   contents of the SCRIPT element or in
>   an external file. If the src attribute
>   is not set, user agents must interpret
>   the contents of the element as the
>   script. If the src has a URI value,
>   user agents must ignore the element's
>   contents and retrieve the script via
>   the URI